# Use html2canvas with jsPDF to save a PDF of a page

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to create a PDF from the contents of a div. I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). The problem is none of my styles are passed, thus the PDF looks off. I then came across an [article](http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html) that uses [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to take a screenshot of the page.

When I try the example provided it gives me this error:

```
uncaught exception: Invalid orientation: [object object] <unknown>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Here is the JS I am using:

```
(function(){
var content = $('#content'),
    cache_width = content.width(),
    a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  // for a4 size paper width and height

$('#pdf').on('click',function(){
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    createPDF();
});
//create pdf
function createPDF(){
    getCanvas().then(function(canvas){
        var 
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
        doc = new jsPDF({
          unit:'px', 
          format:'a4'
        });     
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save("{{this.['Student Last Name']}}-{{this.['Student Name']}}-umpire-incident-report.pdf");
        content.width(cache_width);
    });
}

// create canvas object
function getCanvas(){
    content.width((a4[0]*1.33333) -80).css('max-width','none');
    return html2canvas(content,{
        imageTimeout:2000,
        removeContainer:true
    }); 
}

}());
```

Comment: @Kaiido - Even if I define the orientation it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: can't repro : http://jsfiddle.net/qzLwh2bb/

Comment: @Kaiido - It's something in my CSS. I remove the stylesheet and it works. Add it back, it breaks.

Comment: some css hasn't been implemented into html2canvas, could you check the width/height of the canvas before using the `addImage()` method? Also a live example could help.

Comment: @Kaiido - Found the problem. See my answer to what was happening. Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you want to keep those gradients, you could make them [solid background-image with canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34271414/3702797) before calling html2canvas. Still strange it does throw an error though.

Comment: @Kaiido - Thanks for the tip. Not a big deal for these gradients so I just switch it back to a solid color.

Comment: Ps, still can't repro actually : http://jsfiddle.net/qzLwh2bb/1/

Comment: @Kaiido - That's fascinating and very curious to why it breaks for me and doesn't in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, removing my CSS solves the problem. As @Kaiido pointed out, html2canvas hasn't implemented some CSS.

I have the following CSS in my stylesheet:

```
hr{
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    margin:1rem 0;
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

When I remove the gradients, it works perfectly fine. Instead of removing this code from my CSS, I can simply override using inline styles and it works fine!